# How to do a fulltext search over multiple tables (left joined) at once?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I've got a table named Customer, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    Id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(100) NOT NULL)
```

with other dependent tables, e.g. Address

```
CREATE TABLE Address(
    Id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerId bigint NOT NULL,
    Street varchar(100) NOT NULL)
```

I want to search on the fields `Name` and `Street`.

I thought about creating a view and then defining a fulltext index on it, but then I found out, that using left join is forbidden.

Inner join won't work, because I would lose data where no address exists.

How could I do a fulltext search?